Delphi 12.1 Community Edition with Android 14
One year ago I could use Delphi 11 CE to develop for Android 14 with success.
I installed one week ago the newest 12.1 Community Edition on a new, clean install Win 11, even java was missing on it. The Delphi installer installed the Android platform without any problem.
Now even the simpliest Android apps are not running stable on Android 14 for me. 
Like I create a new Multi-device application project, with MasterDetail template and try to run it.
Android 14 / Realme GT 2 Pro
I tried with SDK 25.2.5, SDK 35.0.2, with 32 bit, 64 bit, none of them runs correctly.
The app is intalled, starts but halts after a few seconds with exception class 10 with 64 bit, SDK 35
It is intalled, starts but halts after a few seconds with exception Segmentation fault 11 with 32 bit, SDK 25
I put a debug breakpoint on project source Application.Initialize but either halts before reaching it or not stopping at it;
Android 9 / Samsung S8
Seems to work perfectly, both SDK, both 32 and 64 bit
Debugging works fine.
Thank you for your help

Here is the AndroidManifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- BEGIN_INCLUDE(manifest) -->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.embarcadero.MasterDetailApplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="34" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
    <queries>

    </queries>
    <application
        android:persistent="False"
        android:restoreAnyVersion="False"
        android:label="MasterDetailApplication"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:largeHeap="False"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">



        <!-- Trigger Google Play services to install the backported photo picker module. -->
        <service
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.metadata.ModuleDependencies"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="false"
            tools:ignore="MissingClass">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.metadata.MODULE_DEPENDENCIES" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="photopicker_activity:0:required" android:value="" />
        </service>

        <!-- Our activity is a subclass of the built-in NativeActivity framework class.
             This will take care of integrating with our NDK code. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.embarcadero.firemonkey.FMXNativeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="MasterDetailApplication"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize|screenLayout|uiMode"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="MasterDetailApplication" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="com.embarcadero.rtl.notifications.NotificationAlarm" />

    </application>
</manifest>
<!-- END_INCLUDE(manifest) -->


did you ask for some permissions ? can you show the manifest file ?

I did not ask for any permissions, did not change the manifest file.
Though if I check it, by default lots of permissions are set. I see that some of them are depreciated.  I switched off all of them. The manifest is seen below.
After that, on Android 14, 32 bit, with SDK 25.2.5, it is installed, starts, after some seconds it halts with this screen:
https://1drv.ms/i/s!AtZV8piGQAyPi84QxwM-F7slnQmunw?e=RTdoZ8

The screen shot above is of Android 14, 64 bit actually.
I embedded the manifest xml into the question above.
